# where to declare entities and services in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

where is the best place to declare the entities and the services used in a controller? in the constructor or in the action?

```
    public class CourseController : Controller
    {
        MyEntities entities; //DECLARE THIS HERE?
        private readonly IMyService _service; //DECLARE THIS HERE?

        public MyController()
        {
             entities = new MyEntities(); //INITIALIZE HERE?
            _service = new MyService(_entities); //INITIALIZE HERE?
        }


        public ActionResult Detail(int ID)
        {
            using (MyEntities _entities = new MyEntities ()) //OR DECLARE AND INITILIZE HERE?
            {
                IMyService _service = new MyService(_entities); //OR DECLARE AND INITILIZE HERE?
                var myCourse = _service.GetCourseById(ID);

                return View(myCourse);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare them in the constructor and provide an overload so I could inject fakes for unit testing purposes.

```
    private readonly MyEntities entities;
    private readonly IMyService _service;

    public MyController()
    {
        _entities = new MyEntities();
        _service = new MyService(_entities);
    }

    public MyController(MyEntities myEntities, IMyService myService)
    {
         entities = myEntities;
        _service = myService;
    }
```

Comment: I would take it one step further and use a dependency injection container. Ninject is extremely easy to set up and learn. Just install the Ninject.MVC3 Nuget package and set up the dependencies in the file it creates in the App_Start folder.